# Как передать переменную php в style?

Tags: php

У меня есть переменная с названием картинки, я пытаюсь воспользоваться ей, чтоб установить фон картинки, но ничего не происходит

когда пишу вручную картинка отображается

```
<style>
   body {
    background: url(uploads/<?php echo $name;?>);
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
        if(isset($name) and !empty($name)){
            $location = 'uploads/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
        }
    }
    echo "$name"; // проверил значение - правильное
?> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас php-код выполняется уже после того, как вы вывели стили для фона. В этот момент переменная `$name` еще не существует. Вынесите php-код выше по тексту, так, чтобы он был выше `<style>`.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if  (isset($name) and !empty($name) ) {
        $location = 'uploads/';

        if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location . $name)) {
            echo 'File uploaded successfully';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }
}
?>

<style>
    body {
        background: url(uploads/<?php echo $name;?>);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: не сработало, @Yuri Pokhylko

Comment: Проверьте содержимое переменной $name. Возможно, она пустая.

Comment: Проверил, выводит название картинки, возможно фон формируется до объявления картинки(переменной)?

Comment: Еще возможно, что неверный путь к картинке, проверьте

Comment: Когда ввожу то же название только вручную картинку показывает, я так понимаю, что путь верный

Comment: Значит смотрите как в переменную попадает значение, там где-то ошибка

Comment: Не особо понимаю, где может возникнуть ошибка, если значение правильное передается, обновил код, возможно я неправильно понимаю суть ошибки

Comment: Например, распространенная ошибка, когда путают русские и латинские буквы в названии. Чаще всего, это буква C. В общем, попробуйте переименовать файл или взять другой.

Comment: PHP-код у вас выполняется раньше, чем вы выводите переменную, я надеюсь? Он должен стоят выше по тексту, чем `<style>`.

Comment: Этот момент я не знаю, переменную использую в <head><style>. php-код в body пишу и объявляю тут же

Comment: Тогда понятно) У вас php-код выполняется уже после того, как вы вывели стили для фона. В этот момент переменная `$name` еще даже не существует. Вынесите php-код выше по тексту, так, чтобы он был выше `<style>`.

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо. Опустил `<style>` в конец и заработало.

Comment: Поправил ваш код и внес в свой ответ.